# Argue that $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0<x\leq 1, 0<y^2+z^2\leq x\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}).$ (Borel set))

Tags: measure-theory

**Problem:**

> Argue that the set
> $$A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0<x\leq 1, 0<y^2+z^2\leq x\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$$
> is $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}).$

---

**My attempt:**
It's known that all open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n).$ My idea was to deconstruct $A$ into smallere open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and use set operations to again construct $A.$
I define:
$$B=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0<x\}$$
$$C=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x\leq 1\}$$
$$D=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : y^2+z^2-x\leq 0\}$$
The arguement now is that $B,C,D$ are all open or closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which make all of them $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^3).$ I can now take the intersection of $B,C,D$ and recreate $A$:
$$A=B\cap C \cap D=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0<x\leq 1, 0<y^2+z^2\leq x\} \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^3).$$

It seems legit, but i still feel like i'm missing out on something.

Comment: Define $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Comment: $\mathscr{B}$ for Bounded, or Borel set ?

Comment: Sorry, it's a Borel set.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0<x\leq 1, y^2+z^2\leq x\}=B\setminus [0,1]\times\{0\}\times\{0\}$$
where $B=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0\le x\leq 1, y^2+z^2\leq x\}$.

Since $B$ is closed and the line segment $[0,1]\times\{0\}\times\{0\}$ is also closed, and difference of closed sets is Borel measurable, we're done.

Comment: A is defined as
$A={(,,)∈ℝ^3:0<≤1,0<^2+^2≤}$
Notice the $0<z^2+y^2\leq x$

Comment: @Flems, Corrected now. Please check.